# AngularJS searching from navbar in view

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a navbar on my page that has an input on it that I want to search a view, that should load in index.html after the user types in their search items.  I can only figure out how to search with an input if it's in the same page that the table of ng-repeat items is in.  Is there a way to search the table outside of the view?  I've created a plnkr.  It doesn't work.  I'm not sure how to make it work.  http://plnkr.co/edit/nqChzn5OATNMeSZL7ItJ?p=preview

Here is some of my code:

navbar

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" ng-model="vm.query">
```

Here is my table where the data displays.

```
<table ng-if="query" class="table table-hover table-responsive" >
       <thead>     
           <tr>
               <th>
                   ({{filteredResults.length}}) Results Found
               </th>
           </tr>       
        <tr>
            <td>Acc. ID</td>
            <td>Acc. Name</td>
            <td>Acc Address</td>
            <td>City</td>
            <td>Zip</td>
            <td>Phone</td>
            <td>Parent Name</td>
            <td>Account Type</td>
            <td>Account Status</td>
            <td>Credit Term</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="result in vm.results | filter:query as filteredResults">
            <td>{{ result.accountId }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.accountName }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.address }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.city }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.state }}</td>
            <td>{{ reuslt.zip }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.phone }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.parentName }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.accountType }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.accountStatus }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.accountStatus }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Is it possible to do what I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at your plunker and I don't believe that your code hasn't initialized angular. I can't see an ng-app tag anywhere in your code.

That a side, you will be able to use any input to filter/search (via. various implementations) so long as the input and table are contained with your ng-app and controller parts of the DOM. Otherwise you won't be able to access it the controller.

Can I suggest that you distill your question down? give the smallest amount of code that demonstrates your problem.

here's a rough outline:

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="cntrl">
   <!-- nav bar -->
   <div>
      <input ng-model="filterVal"/>
   </div>
   <!-- table -->
   <div>
      <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="r in data.rows | filter:filterVal">....</tr>
      </table>
   </div>
</body>
```

Here's a plunker where the default filter functionality is working: http://plnkr.co/edit/GDJs5xTCpqq48SDFTk67

If you need to have your nav bar outside of your app/controller or in an different controller (etc.) then there are solutions to this.

---

Assuming you are using ui-route, this is how to use a service to communicate between controllers:

functioning example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/fZZLUvlHO9zUFwQYd1an?p=preview

Eggheads video:
https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-sharing-data-between-controllers

Comment: not entirely accurate ... can use scope events or service to communicate between controller

Comment: Agreed, lots of options.

Comment: @TobyGWilliams My example comes from a much bigger application that does include ng-app, and a reference to angular.  The actual application is functioning properly, I just don't know how to do the search bar outside of the view that has the table in it.  I just forgot to add it to the plnkr I created.  Is there anyway either of you could help me with code on how to do this?  Or point me towards a tutorial that says how to do this?

Comment: @TobyGWilliams I also took some of the code out of my above sample so it is easier to read.  I often get people on Stackoverflow saying I don't add enough detail, so I thought it was better to add more code example than less.

Comment: @TobyGWilliams I looked at your plunker, but it doesn't make any sense to me.  You have everything in the same view.  My navbar, and my grid are in different views.

Comment: @hollyquinn I have been guessing you have multiple views and/or different controllers in play. I created the plunker to show the simplest possible scenario. Are you using ng-route or ui-route in your application?